# Why I get null's in query result?

Tags: orientdb

I have this model

Note -> Keyword

where one note have multiple keywords that describe it. I have this Vertex:

[image]

As you can see in "Out Edges" it have 3 Noticia_keys.
If you go to graph you get this:

[image]

All ok. But if I run this query:

```
select @rid as rid, out(Noticia_keys).name as claves from #12:2
```

I get this output:

[image]

Where it that **null** come from?

---

New data: 
Since I have clear the DB I have new records. This is a trace of one and the problem remains.

[image]

Both query suggested by Alessandro return nothing.
Michela: the Vertex are added through the library [ODBOGM](https://github.com/mdre/odbogm/) that translate Object to Vertex. It the binary API with addVertex and addEdge.

Comment: Hi @Marcelo which version are you using?

Comment: Hi. I have update to v2.2.8

Comment: Perhaps, have you insert a null value? Because this could be an explanation of this behavior

Comment: No, nothing. Now I have clear the db and debug it again but with the same result.
I do not see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you delete some vertices or something?

Comment: I delete all Notice (Noticia) an add one again with worse result. Now I have this output: [null,"MPA","Robo",null] . Two null's!!

Comment: Is something with the DB. I switch to my TestDB and a similar query run fine. So is something internal to the DB instance.

Comment: How did you insert the new value, and how did delete all Noticia?

Comment: Could you post the result of these query ```select out,in from Noticia_keys where out=#12:2``` and ```select from Noticia_keys where in=null```

Answer (score 2):

Well! Finally I found the error!!
What was wrong:

In the query

```
select @rid as rid, out(Noticia_keys).name as claves from #12:2
```

the **out** parameter has no quote. The query work fine if you type:

```
select @rid as rid, out("Noticia_keys").name as claves from #12:2
```

I found the error just running this query

[image]

that show me in the "claves" column, rid's of other vertex like Medios (#16:) and Fuentes (#17:). The real problem is that the query not fail if it not found a property on a vertex. Since I request "name", the Keyword vertex response correctly but the others out's return null.

Thank for your time!